# Export Rad Grid to PDF with html header

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid, export-to-pdf

I am using telerik rad grid. I want to export the grid with html header.

I want to manually add the header html. For that i am reading the html file and then assigning it to raw html as below.

This id the final html that is getting generated by after reading the file.

```
<div style='width:500px;float:left;'>
<div style='width:250px;float:left;'>
    <div>
        Customer : sachin
    </div>
    <div>
        Machine  : New Machine
    </div>
    <div>
        Build    : R956
    </div>
</div>
<div style='width:250px;float:left;'>
    <div>
        Date     : 11/7/2014 5:15:05 AM
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is how i am assigning it. The caption variable contains html shown above.

```
 protected void radPreview_PdfExporting(object sender, GridPdfExportingArgs e)
    {
        e.RawHTML = Caption + e.RawHTML;
    }
```

> ```
> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Telerik.Web.Apoc.Layout.BlockArea' to type
> ```
>
> 'Telerik.Web.Apoc.Layout.AreaContainer'.   at
>   Telerik.Web.Apoc.Fo.Flow.BlockContainer.Layout(Area area)   at
>   Telerik.Web.Apoc.Fo.Flow.Block.Layout(Area area)   at
>   Telerik.Web.Apoc.Fo.Flow.Flow.Layout(Area area, Region region)   at
>   Telerik.Web.Apoc.Fo.Flow.Flow.Layout(Area area)   at
>   Telerik.Web.Apoc.Fo.Pagination.PageSequence.Format(AreaTree areaTree) 
>   at Telerik.Web.Apoc.StreamRenderer.Render(PageSequence pageSequence)
>   at Telerik.Web.Apoc.Fo.FOTreeBuilder.EndElement()   at
>   Telerik.Web.Apoc.Fo.FOTreeBuilder.Parse(XmlReader reader)

I tried to search a lot on this issue. please suggest me the solution that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a lot on this issue i found the issue from one old telerik thread.

PDF export will not handle two scenarios.

1) Div tag with fixed width or height. ( this was the issue in my case )

2 ) Div tags with absolute position.

Hope this will help someone.